# C++ Change output executable name in code

Tags: c++

I have a question... Is it possible to somehow change output executable name in code? I mean something like

```
#ifdef COMPILE_DEBUG
...Name="Client_debug.exe"
#endif
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course it is. Bad question. Voting to close. Next please.

Comment: Not in C++ code. This is something you should be doing in a makefile.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: @Jesper How exactly would you do that?

Comment: @mel I think it's quite clear - he wants to generate different executables dependent on code in a C++ file containing the code for the executable.

Comment: @latedeveloper Similarly, Jesper thinks it's quite clear he wants to do something else.

Comment: @latedeveloper obviously he's at some build system stage - pre compiler - so he can change whatever he wants before it is passed to the compiler proper (in this case, the pre-processor).

Comment: If he wants to do something else, then the question should be about that.

Comment: @jesper that makes no sense at all. And if you think he can do what he wants, as your first comment suggests, tell him how to do it.

Comment: @latedeveloper have you never injected a script into your build process that subtly modified the environment or re-wrote files before passing them on to the real compiler?  If not, then fine - I hope you never have to; but it's completely possible. Both using cmake, scons or even plain makefile's.

Comment: @jesper Please explain how modifying the contents of a C++ source file can change the name of the generated executable.

Comment: Modifying the arguments passed to the compiler can change the name of the generated executable.

Comment: @Jesper That was not what he was asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The C++ language doesn't provide any portable mechanism to do that.

Once you start talking about particular platforms, you change the executable name in the .vcxproj file (or whatever build system you are using) - which ends up changing options passed to the linker.

Some compilers have platform specific pragmas to pass options to the linker - they *might* be able to do this.  But at that point you have to edit your .vcxproj file to pass suitable #defines in - why not just change the output file?